# R: Combine groups with overlapping elements

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with group ids and their members. I would like to combine all groups that share a member.

To illustrate, I might have something like this:

```
data.frame(group  = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
           member = c( 1,   2,   2,   3,   4,   5))
```

Here, groups a and b belong to a larger group, because they share member 2. I would like to add an identifier for these large groups so that I would end up with something like:

```
data.frame(largeg = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
           group  = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
           member = c( 1,   2,   2,   3,   4,   5))
```

How can I go about implementing this in R? A solution that works in a magrittr chain would be awesome. But it's not a requirement.

(I don't care what the identifiers look like. They can all be numbers, I just used capital letters, lowercase letters, and numbers here to clarify things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think at your data as a graph, you see that smaller groups belong to the same large group if they are connected through a member. The `igraph` package can solve this problem (`df` is your original `data.frame`):

```
require(igraph)
df$largeg<-components(graph_from_data_frame(df))$membership[df$group]
#  group member largeg
#1     a      1      1
#2     a      2      1
#3     b      2      1
#4     b      3      1
#5     c      4      2
#6     c      5      2
```

You can of course change the names of the `largeg` after.

---

As a function that can be added to a `magrittr` chain:

```
FindComponents <- function(df, group, id) {
  df <- df[, c(group, id)]
  gr <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
  as.vector(components(gr)$membership[df[[group]]])
}
```

Usage:

```
df %>%
  mutate(largeg = FindComponents(., 'group', 'id'))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing out the graph-nature of the problem. I took the liberty of adding a magrittr/dplyr chainable function to your answer.